# Http port 80 is not open but Port 8080 is opened and website not opening

Tags: networking

I have redhat linux server GNU. The port 80 is not open there, and port 8080 is opened. Now i am trying to open a website. How to know which port apache using and if port 80 is not open can http://xxxx (website URL) work? As of now for me the website is not opening.And when i am typing this in the browser http://xxx the page is not loading and url showing is https://xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to know which port apache is using to deliver web content. You can use below commands to check the ports.

1. For a general check if an app is running you could just use
   “ps aux | grep apache2” Or "ps aux | grep httpd" for redhat/centos.
2. lsof -i list open ports and the corresponding applications.

By default, HTTP uses port 80 and HTTPS uses port 443, but you can use a URL followed by opened port like http://www.example.com:8080/path/ which specifies that the web browser connects instead to port 8080 of the HTTP server.

If you have a secure socket layer certificate (SSL) on your website, you can automatically redirect visitors to the secured (HTTPS) version of your site for a secure connection.